# Excel VBA - how can I transpose data from one column to different columns until a specified characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet 1 with multiple rows in column A. I need to transpose them to worksheet 2, then go down 1 row and repeat every time a cell in sheet 1 that begins with "icode: " followed by a code in the same cell.

This is what I have so far to transpose and go down 1 row, but stuck at automating it so it selects all rows in column A of Worksheet 1, until it comes across "icode:" followed by random number and then repeats the entire process.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    True, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select


End Sub
```

The data from Worksheet 1, column A looks like this(every line is a different row, including the blank lines):

```
icode: iA4, type: question

Label: Bu

Responses

1: N

2: G

3: S

4: W

5: F

6: We

icode: iA8, type: question

Label: Red

Responses

1: O

2: R

3: T

4: B

5: On

6: Ont

7: A

icode: iA13, type: question

Label: T
Codeer de laatste keer in de LAATSTE 90 DAGEN

Responses
```

etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us a visual of what your expected result is? It's a little difficult to visualize based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Query** it is an add-in for Excel 2010+. In Excel 2016 it is known as **Get & Transform** and comes by default.

Put your data as **Format as Table** and then in the **Query Editor** use this **Power M Code** that you can copy and paste in **Advance Editor**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column1] <> null)),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "icode") then [Column1] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Custom"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"Group", each _, type table}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Group"}),
    RemoveCustom = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Group", each Table.RemoveColumns(_,{"Custom"})}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.TransformColumns(RemoveCustom, {"Group", each Table.Transpose(_)}),
    #"Expanded Group" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Group", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"})
in
    #"Expanded Group"
```

[image]

[image]

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pVNpRucitk&index=1&list=PLu68w-i-LuMlI2ThnNuF2fGivDNYrqjfX) you can find and example about how to use some features in **Power Query**